# Flattening animation to UV map

Tags: animation, uv, export

Is there a way to create a animation render that is exported to a UV map (or UV map like) export? In this particular instance, I would like to create a physics simulation (for instance, fluid pouring down a couple of simple cubes.) Or more simply a spotlight source moving around on the cubes. I would then like to export the animation with the faces of the cubes unwrapped, so that another piece of software can warp the 2D image onto actual 3-dimensional cubes.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand your use case. Why wouldn't you just export the animation if you want to have a 3D scene anyway? Do you mean something like an animated texture for low poly models, e.g. for a game? Currently you can only bake a single texture in Cycles at once, but this could be automated through a python script to create a bake for every frame of the animation.

Comment: The difference is that I'm trying to project via a video projector onto actual objects rather than viewing the animation on a flat/2D screen. I use projection software (Watchout) that allows me to easily warp imagery to 3D objects (in real space), however, I believe the perspective inherent to Blender's camera would unnecessarily distort the animation before Watchout has the opportunity to warp the projected image. If there is a way to post images, I could post a single frame of an example animation that shows the various sides of a building that is video mapped.

Comment: I just discovered the Orthographic Camera mode which may get me closer to what I'm aiming for...but it still only provides a limited view of the virtual object.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that this would be applied to real life objects. The question is what kind of images does Watchout need for this task. Do you need textures for a UV unwrapped 3D object or do you need renders from a camera perspective at the same position the projector would be positioned IRL or something else entirely? If you know that we can likely help you achieve that.

Comment: You can edit your question and add images to it.